# Jenkins node disappear after adding new node

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins node disappear after adding new node

I add the new node through Jenkins GUI and I have about 118 active nodes. After the addition the new node appears but one of the already existing nodes disappears and any job running on the disappeared node starts to throw the following java exception

```
Execution of script [machine_clean.groovy] failed - java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot
invoke method getChannel() on null object
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.util.GroovyScript$ScriptlerExecutionException:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getChannel() on null object
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.util.GroovyScript.call(GroovyScript.java:132)
at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:47)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.builder.ScriptlerBuilder.perform(ScriptlerBuilder.java:242)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:814)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:522)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1896)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getChannel() on null object
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:34)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$getChannel.call(Unknown Source)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:54)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.util.GroovyScript.call(GroovyScript.java:123)
```

Is there a limit on the number of supported node/executors? any idea how to fix this?

Comment: No, fhere is not a limit on the number of nodes. I have amlost 10 000 on a single instance. The problem ia is that we have no idea how your jenkins configuration was done.

Comment: is it limited to the number of CPUs or the RAM of the Jenkins host machine? let me know what info do u want and I will supply. I run using java -DJENKINS_HOME=$JENKINSHOME/jenkins_ws  -jar $JENKINSHOME/jenkins.war_v2.332.1  --webroot=$JENKINSHOME/jenkins_ws/war --httpPort=8080  --debug=0 --handlerCountMax=300 --handlerCountMaxIdle=50